# Laravel 5 includes without blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to include a file on my index page. In php I use something like `include('include/header.php');` 
or in larvel 4 I used `include(app_path().'/views/includes/header.php');` 
My question is...How is it done in Laravel 5 since the whole framework has changed folder structures and what not?  It seems that app_path() is not longer valid.  Also, I do not want to leverage blade syntax.  Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: I think laravel 5 is also the same 
[lar-5 doc path](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths)

Comment: `<?php include(app_path().'/resources/views/includes/includes/header.php'); ?>` This is what I have and I tried moving up a directory but it didnt work.  The app_path looks for only folders in app directory...Therefore it doesnt want to work.  See below for error:

`ErrorException in index.php line 1:
include(C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\SFP Projects\chyall-pharma\app./resources/views/includes/includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `base_path` because the views are not outside off the app directory. Also you can pass the path to the function, no need for string concatenation

```
include(base_path('resources/views/includes/header.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
include(app_path().'/../resources/views/includes/header.php');
```